# Signals error when i execute my npm package

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vue.js

I created a TS package and published it on npm.
When I tested my package on a simple ts project, it works, but when I tested it on a vue or react project, I got this error.

```
signals.js?2678:30 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'signals' of undefined
at normalizeSignal (signals.js?2678:30)
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at getSignals (signals.js?2678:10)
at getSignalsByName (main.js?578e:9)
at eval (main.js?578e:23)
at Object../node_modules/human-signals/build/src/main.js (chunk-vendors.js:1343)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849)
at fn (app.js:151)
at eval (error.js?b472:2)
at Object../node_modules/ytb-d/node_modules/execa/lib/error.js
```

And I don't know why.
The errors refer to a package I use in my library.
My package on npm is ytb-d.
If anyone has a solution

Comment: Do you use webpack in your simple project?. could you add more information about your build process?

Comment: No just ts-node and typescript

Comment: did you try create-react-app --typescript for your react project?

Comment: Yes of course, all my project works in typescript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my tsconfig  in my simple it's just :

```
   {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs",
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "target": "es2017",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "outDir": "dist",
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "declaration": true,
      "paths": {
        "*": ["node_modules/*"]
      }
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules", ".vscode"]
  }
```

Comment: Hi @tibdev78, you can edit your question and add this post to that, that is the better alternative. [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)